# I am getting an error when I execute a delete query

Tags: sqlite

I am executing the following query

```
DELETE FROM List,Tree WHERE List.CatID = Tree.CatID AND List.ID = '1' AND Tree.Cat = '332'
```

but I run into following error

```
near ",": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax for delete statement is this

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE somecolumn=somevalue
```

So you cannot use 2 tables in a single delete query by separating them with a comma..

You need to do something like

```
DELETE something FROM table_name INNER JOIN...
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing but not sure what does trigger the issue.

Comment: because you are joining 2 tables here

Comment: but I have to join to find the row what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete only from one table at a time, and you have to rewrite the join as a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM List
WHERE ID = '1'
  AND CatID IN (SELECT CatID
                FROM Tree
                WHERE Cat = '332')
```